# Sending text via socket from android app (client) to Win32 app (server)

Tags: android, sockets, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I need to send a text from an android application (delphi) to a server application on windows. The windows application uses TServerSocket. So I would need something like:

```
ClientSocket.Socket.SendText('MyText');
```

However, in android (multi device application) there is no TClientSocket component, even adding the dclsockets package manually. So, what would be a compatible component to send text from android to windows via socket?

The windows application (server) that will receive the message is already developed and listens to the message by using the TServerSocket component.

Comment: Use the Socket class. Or if you use Delphi isnt there an Indy TCPClient? I wonder why they dropped TClientSocket. It was always installable afterwards.

Comment: I dont know about TClientSockets but you could send text(android) to server(windows)with datasnap http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Developing_DataSnap_Applications

Comment: @greenapps `TClientSocket` is Windows-only, as it is intimately tied to Winsock. For a cross-platform solution, Delphi ships with Indy pre-installed, you can use its `TIdTCPClient` component, ie: `IdTCPClient1.Connect; IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write('MyText');`

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Thanks for the tip! I would like to know, if you could help me, what may be the reason why on Android I get the message "Socket Error # 111 Connection refused." Windows firewall is disabled. When debugging the application, targeting for windows works correctly.

Comment: @Marcoscdoni "connection refused" usually means either 1) you are connecting to the wrong Host and/or Port; 2) the Host/Port is correct, but no server socket is listening on it; 3) a server socket is listening but its backlog of pending clients is full; or 4) a firewall is blocking the connection.